# Angular ng-model filter with a predefined word

Tags: javascript, angularjs, predefined-variables

From the angular example [page](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter) 
I've tried this example and works

```
 Search: <input ng-model="searchText">
    <table id="searchTextResults">
      <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText">
```

But I want with angular define a string within HTML

I need such a construction  for my website were  products frequely has a price change. These prices I grab from a database. Depend on which webpage   I am i want to show a price from the database

something like:

```
<ng-model="searchText = John">
```

So without having an `input`.

Answer (score 0):

To set a value for `searchText`, just initialize it in your controller:

```
$scope.searchText = 'John';
```

Otherwise, you can use `ng-init`, but this should really be reserved for scenarios that require initialization in the view:

```
<div ng-init="searchText='John'">{{searchText}}</div>
```

Comment: that's not what i need. 
I've multiple webpages which call the same controller (this controller grabs a database). Each webpage should make a different view, with data from this controller.

Comment: Just define ng-init and ng-model on the same element: `<input ng-init="searchText='John'" ng-model="searchText">`

Comment: @DmitryEvseev The OP says, "without having an input".  Not sure what this means... :)

Comment: @DmitryEvseev Evseev Your solution works!  It would be perfect if i could hide the 'input box', but i will figure that out somehow, thank you for your comment

Comment: @DavinTryon I meant without using the 'input' element.

Comment: @Richard Yep, missed the input remark. You're not tied to input here. The `ng-init` directive can be used on any element. You could use it on a table even: `<table id="searchTextResults" ng-init="searchText='John'">`. But think about some good consistent place. If you're bootstrapping controller with `ng-controller` then use `ng-init` also on that element.